# TableView no Separator line xamarin forms

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms

I need to display a bunch of settings and wondering if i can hide the line divider in the table view.  I have found few solutions googling but none of them work.
I have tried using a renderer in android and setting the control divider to 0 or -1 but nothing.

eg
https://forums.xamarin.com/discussion/76380/seperator-lines-in-tableview

Is it possible to hide the divider?

Comment: What have you tried? Could you please a basic demo?

Comment: Think the problems exists, because the CellAdapter has fixed Divider colors... https://github.com/xamarin/Xamarin.Forms/blob/4c00ac34f69d0d1640c24f0dcc8b59a971d1063c/Xamarin.Forms.Platform.Android/Renderers/TableViewModelRenderer.cs#L144 so using a CustomRenderer for TableView has no effect.

Comment: @JessieZhang have tried few implementations suggested in the link https://forums.xamarin.com/discussion/76380/seperator-lines-in-tableview but none worked

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try the following code:

MyTableView.cs

```
  public class MyTableView: TableView
{
    public static readonly BindableProperty SeperatorVisibleProperty = 
BindableProperty.Create("SeperatorVisible", typeof(SeparatorVisibility), 
typeof(MyTableView), SeparatorVisibility.Default);
    public SeparatorVisibility SeperatorVisible
    {
        get { return (SeparatorVisibility)GetValue(SeperatorVisibleProperty); }
        set { SetValue(SeperatorVisibleProperty, value); }
    }
}
```

MyTableViewRenderer.cs in Android

```
 [assembly: ExportRenderer(typeof(MyTableView), typeof(MyTableViewRenderer))]
  namespace MyTableViewApp.Droid
  {
 public class MyTableViewRenderer: TableViewRenderer
 {      
    public MyTableViewRenderer(Context context) : base(context)
    {
    }
    protected override void OnElementChanged(ElementChangedEventArgs<TableView> e)
    {
        base.OnElementChanged(e);

        if (Control == null)
            return;

        //var listView = Control as global::Android.Widget.ListView;
        //listView.Divider = new ColorDrawable(Android.Graphics.Color.Transparent);
        //listView.DividerHeight = 0;

        var listView = Control as global::Android.Widget.ListView;
        listView.Divider.SetTint(Color.Transparent.GetHashCode());
        listView.SetHeaderDividersEnabled(false);
        listView.Divider = null;
        listView.DividerHeight = 0;
    }
}
```

}

A sample effect:
[image]